# Foreign key Constraint on delete cascade does not work postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run `DELETE FROM users WHERE id='some_id'` the record on beta_keys table does not get deleted.

beta_keys table:

```
CREATE TABLE beta_keys (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    key VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

users table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR (256) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
    beta_key_id INTEGER,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT users_beta_key_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (beta_key_id)
        REFERENCES beta_keys (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: you have it backwards. When the `beta_keys` row is deleted, the user will be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`users` references `beta_keys`. `delete cascade` works by deleting referencing rows (`users`) when the referenced row (`beta_keys`) is deleted.

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a7495/1